# Rubber Error When installing elasticsearch

Tags: deployment, amazon-ec2, capistrano, elasticsearch

When I try bootstrapping rubber I get this `error: failed: "/bin/bash -l -c 'sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\''  bash -l /tmp/install_elasticsearch'" on tools.**********.com`

How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

Apparently the url for elastic search download is wrong. If you do the following everything should work normally.

Under

**config/rubber/deploy-elasticsearch.rb**

Change the line that says

```
wget --no-check-certificate -qNP /tmp https://github.com/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-#{rubber_env.elasticsearch_version}.zip
```

to

```
wget --no-check-certificate -qNP /tmp http://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-#{rubber_env.elasticsearch_version}.zip
```

Specifically the url has to be changed instead of using

`https://github.com/downloads/` use `http://download.elasticsearch.org/`

[Rubber elastic search error issue 250](https://github.com/wr0ngway/rubber/issues/250)

Comment: Yup, i found that on the github page.  I forgot to add answer